# How to prevent filling getting squeezed out of chocolate coated candies?

Tags: chocolate, candy, melting-chocolate, peanut-butter, chocolate-truffles

I made some chocolate coated peanut butter candy-eggs, and after I dipped the first egg in chocolate and set it on the rack to cool, the filling is getting squeezed out. How can I prevent this?

---

For context, here's the recipe I'm using

- 2 lbs (.9 kg) confectioner's sugar
- 16 oz (453 g) peanut butter
- 12 tbsp (170 g) butter
- 1 tbsp (15 mL) vanilla

Mix those ingredients, add milk as necessary until it becomes a thick cream

Chill in the fridge for an hour, form into egg shapes, chill in the fridge for another hour

Just barely melt some semisweet chocolate chips, dip the eggs in there

---

Here's what the filling looks like as it's getting squeezed out
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I had to guess I would say your filling is not cold enough when you dip it so it starts to melt and pockets of air form when it comes into contact with the warm chocolate, which then doesn't cover the egg properly, causing filling to leak when it warms up a bit.

Try putting the fillings in the freezer for a bit (30 minutes to an hour) after you've shaped them, if possible. This will allow the chocolate to harden far quicker since the filling is much cooler, it should potentially stop the leakage (assuming the problem is the temperature).

For a nice looking coating of chocolate, try adding some cocoa butter to your melted chocolate. This will add a glistening sheen.

Comment: after freezing them I didn't get the leakage.

Comment: That's great, I'm glad it worked.